# Wrap div without using overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

Usually I will use `overflow:hidden` to wrap div.
But is there any other way to wrap divs without using this method?
Because I have some other concern that cannot use hidden overflow.

Comment: Are you looking for a [clearfix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix), maybe? It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code showing what it is you don't want to happen, and tell us what you would like it to do instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap"?

Comment: Use clearfix. Or you can use overflow:auto; too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overflow:auto` in your CSS.